# What is the formula for tangent line?

Tags: calculus

By formula i mean the layout as well. I remember that i was supposed to substract something from f(x). I am having trouble remembering and the answer i found only told me that tangent line was the derivative.

Comment: Yes i am! Can you post it in answers so that i can accept it?

Comment: This is the sort of question that can be answered with a very modest amount of googling.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent#More_rigorous_description  You should do a minimal amount of research before posting a question.

Comment: Unfortunately wikipedia is blocked in my country and i haven't been able to find a site that described it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of the tangent line to the graph of a function $y=f(x)$ through the point $(x_0,f(x_0))$ is given by $y=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0).$